# /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available

Tags: c++, glibc, beagleboneblack, buildroot

I am running a minimal linux configured using Buildroot. All works fine until I run one of my cross-build application on target that produce below error:

`/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available`

The output of `strings /lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` on `TARGET Machine` is:

`GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH`

The output of same above command on `BUILD Machine` is:

`GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH`

Seems like this error comes when there is glibcxx version mismatch.
Then I tried to check `BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP` option in buildroot, but we cant change/update glibcxx version.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe try reisntall libstdc++.so.6 on target machine?

Comment: Sounds like you link to the libraries of your host. Did you look into the `--sysroot` option of gcc? (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) . You can use `buildroot/output/host/xyz/sysroot` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds very much like your build environment is set up wrong.

If you are building your target using Buildroot, then you *must* build your application using the same toolchain and environment too. Two options:

- Build your application out of (Buildroot) tree
- Build your application as a package inside of Buildroot

Please refer to the Buildroot documentation and this [excellent presentation (PDF)](https://elinux.org/images/2/2a/Using-buildroot-real-project.pdf). Specifically pages 27 and 34.

A special case would be if you are dealing with a vendor SDK and toolchain. Then you would need to integrate the vendor toolchain into Buildroot, which is very simple and documented. Anyway, the result must be that you use the same toolchain and headers for both.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I compiled buildroot source using toolchain that matched with target binary application's toolchain.

Comment: In my case, I used linaro toolchain for compiling both buildroot and my target application.